# Is it possible to "dope" glass to change it's refractive index?

Tags: materials

For many purposes, like in the making of achromatic lens combinations, we need transparent media of different refractive indices. Let's assume I want a transparent medium of refractive index of 1.4, how would I go about getting such a material? Can I "dope" it by dissolve some impurities into molten glass mixture and then solidify it later? How would I choose my impurity to add? How do I calculate how much to add?

Comment: Refractive index depends strongly on wavelength but assuming you are in the visible then for a glass/quartz 1.4 is very low indeed and such a material may not exist. If you are in the UV then glass is no good as it absorbs and you need silica or calcite etc. If you want a liquid then there are plenty. Nowadays commercial lens design is hugely sophisticated and so buy the lens you need, don't even think of trying to make anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, yes. That is how they make lenses. If you don't know what impurity to add you can fiddle with the density, which - usually - changes the index of refraction. So you can take some $\ce{PbO}$ or $\ce{B2O3}$ and add to your $\ce{SiO2}$ to get different average densities. Higher density = (probably) higher index. But this is not a 1:1 relation, it is a very noisy correlation for glasses and minerals. The correlation is very good for liquids or mixtures of miscible solvents - and then it is called the [Gladstone-Dale Relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gladstone%E2%80%93Dale_relation)

This used to be a "known" relation and referred to in science but it has fallen out of favor due to other, more explaining relations between more sensible parameters. It is a bit 1700-ish to promote a direct relationship between physical density and optical parameters, especially when you have to disregard the wave nature of photons. The "modern" ones relate to polarizability and permittance - which makes more sense.

Answer (score 5):

Glass doesn't crystallize at all, that's the point. Consequently, unlike crystalline materials, it doesn't have fixed composition. In a way, it can be said that glass *consists of* impurities. And yes, of course, you may change its composition this way or that, so as to tune the refractive index to your purposes.

Further reading: [crown glass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crown_glass_(optics)), [flint glass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flint_glass).

Comment: This quite doesn't answer my question. While I understood that glass doesn't crystallize, are there any calculations involved in finding the amount of impurity to be added? How do I choose the impurity?

Comment: You choose the impurity and the amount of it by looking up the industry reference books. Calculations are kinda possible, but insanely complicated and still not completely reliable.